# SQL 2014 Query for taxi trip data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I’m trying to run a query on the data below using Microsoft SQL 2014.
I want to find amount off passenger per hour and by day the trip distance, fare amount by hour and day and total amount.

[image: taxi trip data]

*PS: I’m new to SQL and I’m doing a class project.*

Comment: Please review [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Where are your efforts, what have you tried?

Comment: please share your expected result

Comment: Also please share your DDL Statement  for the table structure to work on

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic aggregation with some date functions.

```
declare @table table
    (VendorID int, 
    pickup_datetime datetime, 
    passengercount int, 
    trip_distance decimal (4,2),
    fare_amount decimal (4,2),
    tip_amount decimal (4,2),
    tolls_amount decimal (4,2))

insert into @table
values
(1,'1/8/2015 22:22',3,1.55,5.65,1,1.22),
(1,'1/8/2015 22:45',1,2.35,2.65,2,0.22),

(1,'1/8/2015 23:03',1,4.55,9.55,2,4.22),

(2,'1/9/2015 03:03',3,1.54,0.65,2,1.22),
(2,'1/9/2015 03:16',2,2.05,1.15,3,11.12),

(2,'1/9/2015 04:22',1,3.50,4.25,2,1.83),
(2,'1/10/2015 06:44',4,4.44,3.63,1,1.99)

select
    VendorID, 
    cast(pickup_datetime as date) as DT,
    datepart(hour,pickup_datetime) as HR,
    sum(passengercount) as TotalPassengers,
    sum(fare_amount) + sum(tip_amount) + sum(tolls_amount) as TotalAmount
from 
    @table
group by
    VendorID,
    cast(pickup_datetime as date),
    datepart(hh,pickup_datetime)
```